# Prolog's detecting change in list

Tags: prolog

I would like to write a predicate `find_difference([A|B],[P|Q],[C-D|E-F])` to find the difference between the list `[A|B]` and `[P|Q]`, and give the result like `[C-D|E-F]`, C indicates that the change happen in the Nth sublist while `D` tells that the change happen at the Nth element of that sublist (the change in every sublist will only be one character).
So the query and expected result will be like:

```
find_difference([[a,b,c],[w,t]],[[a,b,d],[w,s]],X).
X=[1-3,2-2].
```

can the predicate also deal with the variables? For example:

```
find_difference([[A,B,C],[A,D]],[[A,D,C],[A,S]],X).
X=[1-2,2-2].
```

thank you in advance for any help you can provide.

```
find_difference([],[],1).
find_difference([A|B],[C|D],E):-
    (   A=C ->
        find_difference(B,D,Y),
        E is Y+1
    ;   find_difference(B,D,E)
    ).
```

I can now only manage to get the different values of a list. But if the two list are the same, it will gill a wrong answer. Also, it can not deal with the variables.

```
7 ?- find_difference([A,B,C],[A,B,D],X).
C = D,
X = 4.
```

Why is that?

Comment: Your stated desired result is a list, but your attempt at implementation clearly has an integer result (`E`), not a list result.

Comment: What do you understand by a difference? It is not clear from your question. Rather state what a difference looks like.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's an implementation:

```
find_difference(LA, LB, LDiffs):-
  find_difference(LA, LB, 1, 1, LDiffs).

find_difference([], [], _, _, []).
find_difference([[]|LA], [[]|LB], Row, _, LDiffs):-
  succ(Row, NRow),
  find_difference(LA, LB, NRow, 1, LDiffs).
find_difference([[Item|ATail]|LA], [[Item|BTail]|LB], Row, Col, LDiffs):-
  succ(Col, NCol),
  find_difference([ATail|LA], [BTail|LB], Row, NCol, LDiffs).
find_difference([[AItem|ATail]|LA], [[BItem|BTail]|LB], Row, Col, [Row-Col|LDiffs]):-
  AItem\=BItem,
  succ(Col, NCol),
  find_difference([ATail|LA], [BTail|LB], Row, NCol, LDiffs).
```

You keep track of the current "row" and "column" and check whether each item from the first list matches the item of the second list. If it does not match you add the location on the third list.

First clause of find_difference/5 is the base case (empty lists on first and second argument).

Second clause goes from one "row" to the next one.

Third clause checks whether the first item of the head lists in the first and second arguments unify, in this case you just increment the "column".

Fourh clause checks whether they don't unify, therefore you add the current Row-Col to the "output" list.

In both third and fourth clauses you increment the current column and continue recursion.

Example:

```
?- find_difference([[a,b,c],[w,t]],[[a,b,d],[w,s]],X).
X = [1-3, 2-2]
```

Your second example (using uninstantiated variables) would not yield the result you were expecting:

```
?- find_difference([[A,B,C],[A,D]],[[A,D,C],[A,S]],X).
B = S,
D = S,
X = [] ;
```

because you can unify B and D with S do that the do match.